# IP Cam system suggestions

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, rtsp, ipcam

Though id ask here as it seems like a pool of knowledge

Im wanting to record RTSP streams on my raspberry pi possibly combining my OMV instance, not sure the best solution/setup hence the post.

I want to setup and maintain this internally i.e I dont want to use a 3rd party cloud service.

**Features:**

I want to record on loop 2 streams (storage permitting ~a weeks worth of footage)

- Via RTSP streams as the cameras dont have FTP functionality

Be able to *fairly easily* view the recordings via my computer and android phone

- As seamless as possible (seems the vlc media player app doesn't work with ftp all that well)

Have access to the live streams via the RTSP stream

- The cameras are blocked from accessing the web so the ezviz app will not suffice
- I intend to use my vpn profile whilst out the network to get me back in for functionality

I dont mean for this to be a typical *someone else do the work for me* kind of post, I'm fairly new to raspberry pie's and I have trialled a few software's such as [shinobi](https://hub.shinobi.video/articles/view/dRqw1Cqnty81Aii) which is nice but rather beefy and doesn't give that great mobile access. Also various shell scripts with openRTSP and FFMPEG but seems rather unreliable and not fault tolerant , if the script crashes nothing is recording.

If you could help with any or all of my query id appreciate it,

Cheers

Comment: it isn't `raspberry pie` ... look at the very top of this page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ant Media server for the same. https://antmedia.io/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).